# Web Api gzip compression

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, gzip

I have used this [URL](https://damienbod.com/2014/07/16/web-api-using-gzip-compression/) for the web API compression but when I see the out put in the fiddler header is not zip. there are multiple Zip option are available example GZIP, BZIP2 DEFLATE not sure which one to use kindly help here

I have tried with the below solution and both of them are not working :

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> there are multiple Zip option are available example GZIP, BZIP2 DEFLATE not sure which one to use kindly help here

This list will be sent to the server and let it know about the client side preferences about compression. It means "I first prefer GZIP. If GZIP not supported by the server side then fallback to BZIP2 DEFLATE compression. If BZIP2 DEFLATE not supported then the server will not do any compression."

There is someone who already create a nuget package that use that implementation you just put in your question. The package name is **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression** which install the following two packages :

- **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server**
- **System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client**

If you don't need the client side library then just just the server side package in your Web API project.

To use it you need to modify to add the following line at the end of your `Application_Start` method in **Gloabl.asax.cs**:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

To learn more about this package check this [link](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression).

Comment: Hi
I have fallowed the below steps,
Create the new solution in the VS 2013 web api, added nuget package and configure the Global.ascx .. when i run the sample code and check in fiddler still its not compressed

Comment: You need to configure the header by adding "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" before sending the request to the server. Fiddler don't add it automatically but browsers do.

Comment: @user3227615 have you test what I say in my comment ?

Comment: i have tested as per your suggested step , in postman it show the compressed data and same was not showing in the fiddler. in post man GZip is working fine.  on the client side we need to write any code to decompress the file ..?

Comment: If you are using Browsers no. If you are using Fiddler, you can see a button in the response for decompression. If it works consider to mark it as an answer and open another thread for another issue ;-)